# Cakephp file upload problem

Tags: php, cakephp, uploader

I am using Cakephp as my framework. I have a problem in uploading my files through a form. I am using an Uploader plugin from  [THIS](http://www.milesj.me/resources/script/uploader-plugin)  website.

My php ini file has this piece of code.

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 8M
```

this is from uploader.php  --> plugin file has

```
var $maxFileSize = '5M'; //default max file size
```

In my controller.php file, i use this code to set max file size as 1 MB at runtime.

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->Uploader->maxFileSize = '1M'; 
}
```

In the uploader.php, we perform this ...

```
if (empty($this->maxFileSize)) {
    $this->maxFileSize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize'); //landmark 1
}

$byte = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i', '', $this->maxFileSize);
$last = $this->bytes($this->maxFileSize, 'byte');

if ($last == 'T' || $last == 'TB') {
    $multiplier = 1;
    $execTime = 20;
} else if ($last == 'G' || $last == 'GB') {
    $multiplier = 3;
    $execTime = 10;
} else if ($last == 'M' || $last == 'MB') {
    $multiplier = 5;
    $execTime = 5;
} else {
    $multiplier = 10;
    $execTime = 3;
}


ini_set('memore_limit', (($byte * $multiplier) * $multiplier) . $last);
ini_set('post_max_size', ($byte * $multiplier) . $last);  //error suspected here
ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', $this->tempDir);
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', $this->maxFileSize); //landmark 2
```

EXPECTED RESULT: 
When i try uploading a file that is 2MB of size, it shouldn't take place because maxFileSize is 1MB at run time. So upload should fail.

THE PROBLEM IS :
But it is getting uploaded.

Landmark 1 does not get executed. (in comments)... land mark 2 does not seem to work... 
upload_max_filesize does not get the value from maxFileSize.

Please help me... thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `upload_max_filesize` during the script execution is rather pointless, since by the time the script executes the file is already uploaded and accepted by the server. If you need to reject the file based on size in your script (as opposed to Apache or PHP rejecting it), you need to evaluate the size of the uploaded file and "manually" ignore it if it's too big.

Answer (score 1):

pointless or not it's not even possible to change `upload_max_filesize` with ini_set.

`upload_max_filesize` has the changable flag`PHP_INI_PERDIR` wich means  `Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)`

as a additional comment remember that `post_max_size` should be equal or greater then `upload_max_filesize`